# After on-premise setup of mesibo . Do I need to change this url from client side mesibo-lib.js https://storage.mesibo.com/api/api.php

Tags: mesibo

After on-premise setup of mesibo , Do I need to change anything from mesibo-lib.js end ?

I could see some url in mesibo-lib.js - a.Gc="https://storage.mesibo.com/api/api.php"

Please help to understand here from client side what changes needs to be done.

Im using angularjs client side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud or On-premise, you should use your server to store your files. storage.mesibo.com is only provided for evaluation and files can be regularly cleaned up.

Refer to https://mesibo.com/documentation/tutorials/get-started/file-transfer/